# Messaging people using discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How would I make the message the user is sent predefined so when I do !Message it sends them the message I have preselected within the script for the bot i.e Message = ("Hello") !Message would send the user a message which reads hello

```
from discord.ext import commands
    import discord

    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

    @bot.command(pass_context=True)
    async def Message(ctx, role: discord.Role, *, message):
        for member in ctx.message.server.members:
            if role in member.roles:
                await bot.send_message(member, message)

    @bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        await bot.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name="PlutoIsMyDad"))
        print('Logged in as')
        print(("\nUser Name:"),bot.user.name)
        print(("User Id:"), bot.user.id)
        print(("Command to mass message : !Message (@Role) (Custom Message)  -Without Brackets-"))
        print(" ")


    bot.run('**********', '*************')
```

Comment: Is the message ever going to change?  Do you want to be able to set a message through discord?

Comment: its never going to change i went it to be set within the bots code

Comment: Why don't not without letting `message` as a parameter in `Message`, and just do `await bot.send_message(member, "Hello")`? I don't think you even know how this code functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def Message(ctx):
    await ctx.say("Hello")
```

I recommend that you read the documentation for the api because your code *clearly* is not for what you want to do

http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html